Converting active PowerPoint to text file including table and chart
I found the following macro code for converting a PowerPoint file to a text file: Its perfectly working only from placeholder, shapes, group shapes. I want all the text need to extract from my active presentation. The problem is, Table and chart are not included in this code. so its skipped the table and charts. Is it possible to extract from table also?

  Dim oPres As Presentation
  Dim oSlides As Slides
  Dim oSld As Slide         'Slide Object
  Dim oShp As Shape         'Shape Object
  Dim iFile As Integer      'File handle for output
  iFile = FreeFile          'Get a free file number
  Dim PathSep As String
  Dim FileNum As Integer
  Dim sTempString As String

  #If Mac Then
    PathSep = ":"
  #Else
    PathSep = "\"
  #End If

  Set oPres = ActivePresentation
  Set oSlides = oPres.Slides

  FileNum = FreeFile

  'Open output file

  Set fsObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set xmlFile = fsObject.CreateTextFile(oPres.Path & PathSep & "AllText.txt", True, True) 'the second "true" forces a unicode file.
 
  

  For Each oSld In oSlides    'Loop thru each slide
    ' Include the slide number (the number that will appear in slide's
    ' page number placeholder; you could also use SlideIndex
    ' for the ordinal number of the slide in the file
    xmlFile.writeline "Slide:" & vbTab & CStr(oSld.SlideNumber)

    For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes                'Loop thru each shape on slide
      'Check to see if shape has a text frame and text
      If oShp.HasTextFrame And oShp.TextFrame.HasText Then
        If oShp.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
            Select Case oShp.PlaceholderFormat.Type
                Case Is = ppPlaceholderTitle, ppPlaceholderCenterTitle
                     xmlFile.writeline "Title:" & vbTab & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
                Case Is = ppPlaceholderBody
                     xmlFile.writeline "Body:" & vbTab & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
                Case Is = ppPlaceholderSubtitle
                     xmlFile.writeline "SubTitle:" & vbTab & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
                Case Else
                     xmlFile.writeline "Other Placeholder:" & vbTab & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
            End Select
        Else
            xmlFile.writeline vbTab & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
        End If  ' msoPlaceholder
      Else  ' it doesn't have a textframe - it might be a group that contains text so:
        If oShp.Type = msoGroup Then
            sTempString = TextFromGroupShape(oShp)
            If Len(sTempString) > 0 Then
                 xmlFile.writeline sTempString
            End If
        End If
      End If    ' Has text frame/Has text

    Next oShp
  Next oSld

  'Close output file
  xmlFile.Close

End Sub

Function TextFromGroupShape(oSh As Shape) As String
' Returns the text from the shapes in a group
' and recursively, text within shapes within groups within groups etc.

    Dim oGpSh As Shape
    Dim sTempText As String

    If oSh.Type = msoGroup Then
        For Each oGpSh In oSh.GroupItems
            With oGpSh
                If .Type = msoGroup Then
                    sTempText = sTempText & TextFromGroupShape(oGpSh)
                Else
                    If .HasTextFrame Then
                        If .TextFrame.HasText Then
                            sTempText = sTempText & "(Gp:) " & .TextFrame.TextRange.Text & vbCrLf
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next
    End If

    TextFromGroupShape = sTempText

NormalExit:
    Exit Function

Errorhandler:
    Resume Next

End Function


You'd need to test each shape for .HasTable=True. If so it's a table, so you'd reference the shape's .Table property and from there, step through the table's cell collection to get at the text in each cell.  Charts are a whole different level of complexity; it might be considerably simpler to copy/paste the chart to a new blank slide as EMF, ungroup it several times and grab the text from the individual shapes.

Hi @steve Thanks for the reply.. forget about the chart.. but for me table is a important. I am not familiar in VBA. If it possible kindly help to edit the above code to include table

StackExchange isn't a code-writing service, but I've added an answer below with some sample code that you can adapt to what you're doing.

This isn't an actual answer but you can adapt this code to what you're doing.
Option Explicit

Sub TestTableExtract()
' This tests the text extraction function below
' Select the table you want to test with first!

Dim oSh As Shape
Dim sResult As String

Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

' Call TableExtract to extract the text from the table
' First, test to be sure that the shape IS a table:
If oSh.HasTable Then
    sResult = TableExtract(oSh)
End If

' And show the result
MsgBox sResult

End Sub

Function TableExtract(oSh As Shape) As String
' Extracts text from the table oSh and returns it as a string
' with one line per cell

Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim sText As String
Dim sTemp As String

With oSh.Table
    For lRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
        For lCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
            sTemp = .Cell(lRow, lCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
            If Len(sTemp) > 0 Then
                sText = sText & sTemp & vbCrLf
            Else
                sText = sText & "--" & vbCrLf
            End If
        Next
    Next
End With

TableExtract = sText

End Function

